# Does numpy.log(numpy.prod(y)) not equal numpy.sum(numpy.log(y)) in log-likelihood?

Tags: distributions, likelihood

Does numpy.log(numpy.prod(y)) not equal numpy.sum(numpy.log(y)) in log-likelihood?
y is an n-dimensional array with n probabilities, and it comes from putting n samples into the density function. Obviously, The product of n probability densities is going to be almost zero, i.e., np.prod(y)=0, resulting in np.log(np.prod(y)) = -inf. However,  np.log(y) usually get n negative numbers, so np.sum(np.log(y)) is a scalar. That means that numpy.log(numpy.prod(y)) is not equal to np.sum(np.log(y)) ？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically, they're equal, but hardware has finite precision. If you push its limits, they won't be equal or even close. Truth is `log(prod(y))` may overflow much easier, so the rounding error will be much larger, especially when the number of terms is large.

Moreover, as a general rule of thumb, never compare floating numbers by equality operator. Use `np.isclose` or measure the difference in numbers by an epsilon of your choice.

As shown [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/floating-point-error-in-python/#:%7E:text=It%27s%20a%20problem%20caused%20when,leads%20to%20small%20roundoff%20errors.):

```
>>> 1.2 - 1.0 == 0.2
False
```

Comment: THX buddy, got it